# Why am I failing to get an access token from the Vodapay authorizations/applyToken endpoint with a ‘General business failure’ response?

Tags: vodapay-miniprogram

I am getting the following error:

```
{
"result": {
    "resultCode": "PROCESS_FAIL",
    "resultStatus": "F",
    "resultMessage": "General business failure. No retry."
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the “**salesCode**” should always have a value of “51051000101000000011” The "**paymentRequestId**" is the one you need to have a unique value for each payment.